# How can I test the Microsoft Authentication process using automation?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, automated-tests, microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph Framework. I recently developed a web application with Graph API's integration.

The first time browsing to the page on my app, it redirects the user to Microsoft app login page and prompt for credentials. Once authentication successful then I use the authentication token to get the user's emails and do post processing on those emails.

However, I need to write tests to see if the token is being persisted properly and for the subsequent processing on emails. All my tests are automated tests that are run on jenkins which is not set up to run with a browser. And without having the authentication token, I am unable to test the downstream process. Is there a way to get the token through an API without requiring a browser/user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

For automated tests running in Jenkins, you probably want to use an auth flow that doesn't require the user to login.  Please see the documentation page on [Getting auth tokens without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) for detailed information.

In summary, you can register an app on the [App Registration site](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and add application permissions like `User.Read.All`.  Since the goal is to get tokens that work without a user login, you'll need to grant your app access to run as a service by getting administrator consent. After that one time setup, you can then easily request tokens by [POSTing to the token endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#4-get-an-access-token) with your app info and secret.

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case because the app I am building should only sync emails for some users in an organization. (These are the users that would authorize on the web application). The administrator wouldn't consent to provide an `Email.Read.All` permissions to my app, since that would allow my app to read inboxes from even say, the CEO's mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the [username/password authentication flow](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/), where your test doesn't go through the normal interactive experience.

You need to create a `UserCredential` and use that to acquire a token.

```cs
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(user, password);

public Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(
       string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCredential);
```